# Azure Mobile Services .net Backend Authentication using individual user accounts

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, azure-mobile-services

I have an existing ASP.net Web API that uses Individual User Accounts.

I use it to Signup / ChangePassword / Login etc.
When I login, I receive back a token and then use the token to access the [Authorize] Controllers.

i.e.
[Authorize]
    public class ValuesController : ApiController

I have added the Controllers, DataObjects , Startup.MobileApp and AppNameApiContext from the TODO .net backend for Azure mobile apps to my current API.

i.e 
 public class TodoController : TableController

This works fine for syncing / inserting etc. but if I add [Authorize] to the controller it will always return unauthorized even if I send the same token that I'm using with the other API endpoints.

All the samples I can find using "Custom Authentication for Azure Mobile Apps"
use Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server.Authentication.

How do I use the same login/token to provide authentication to both (ValuesController : ApiController ) 
and the 
(TodoController : TableController)

Many thanks in anticipation

I'm trying to find a solution like

```
app.UseAppServiceAuthentication(new AppServiceAuthenticationOptions
            {
                SigningKey = signingKey,
                ValidAudiences = new[] { hostName },
                ValidIssuers = new[] { hostName },
                TokenHandler = new MyClass (config)
            });


public class MyClass : AppServiceTokenHandler
{
  public override bool TryValidateLoginToken
  (string token,
   string signingKey,
   IEnumerable<string> validAudiences,
   IEnumerable<string> validIssuers,
   out ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal)

  {
     if (CheckIfUserIsAuth(token))
     {
       return true;
     }

     // Or something like 
     // if(token== CurrentUserToker)
     //  { return true};
  }
}
```

However I still receive unauthorized, whether I return true of false.

Comment: Need more information.  (1) How is EasyAuth set up?  (2) What version of the Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client are you using?  (3) How are you logging in?  (4) Do you have any other OWin auth pipeline code?

Comment: Hi,
I'm using a ASP.NET 4.6 Web API template with authentication "Individual user accounts". 

I use that to do standard Api calls from a app.
Currently I make a call to the http://myapi.com/token with an email address and password. It returns a token, I store the token and use the token to access [Authorise] Controllers.

I want to use that same token to access the 
[Authorize]
TodoController : TableController.

The Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client version is 3.0.3. Its the one that come with the TODO Xamarin.Android downloaded from the aure portal

Answer (score 0):

You have started from the wrong point, unfortunately.  You need to start from an Azure Mobile App.  This has the necessary logic in it to authenticate from a mobile device using EasyAuth.  I recommend starting from the tutorial - it has both a frontend and a backend of your choice.  You can then expand as necessary.

Comment: Ok lets call it an existing app that uses a existing API. The API has endpoints like push,get users, get data, create account, send email, forgot password etc. the API is also used from a website as well as a desktop app. 
I now want to move the app from using Sql Lite to Azure Table Sync. 

The answer is to have a duplicated API using EasyAuth?

Comment: Or login twice having a user for the Api and a EasyAuth user.

Comment: Your problem is that the [Authorize] tag is being handled by the Individual Accounts Owin stuff instead of the Azure Mobile Apps Owin stuff, resulting in a conflict.  You need to extract the old Owin stuff and replace it with the Azure Mobile Apps Owin stuff.